# SCI_AUTOCSHOW on Scintilla

Tags: mfc, scintilla

I have a question, when I use

`CallScintilla(SCI_AUTOCSHOW, nLen, (LPARAM)m_strCandidate.c_str())`

to show the window about autocompletion, it works when I input a word but it doesn't always work when I press the backspace button, I wonder if there are some conflicts about the key backspace?

Answer (score 0):

use SCI_AUTOCSETSEPARATOR to set the separator character used to separate words in the SCI_AUTOCSHOW list. The default is the space character.